# Check count before insert data odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How in custom module odoo 9 before insert new record in database, check is record exists?

For example:

If in table project.task we have name "PARIS" and date_deadline "2017-01-01" in code below I need warning before execute...

```py
vals = {'name': 'PARIS','date_deadline': '2017-01-01']}
create_new_task = http.request.env['project.task'].create(vals)
```

Or maybe try get count from project.task where name='PARIS' and date_deadline='2017-01-01' before click on button save!

Any simple solution?

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('date','time') #Time is Many2one
    def _check_existing(self):
        count = self.env['test.module'].search_count([('date','=',self.date),('time','=',self.time.id)])
        print(self.date)  #2017-01-01
        print(self.time.id) #1
        if(count >= 1):
            raise ValidationError(_('DUPLICATE!'))
```

After try insert new record in database where is date = 2017-02-02 and time = 1 get this message:

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_module_time_uniq"
DETAIL: Key (time)=(1) already exists.

Time exist but date is different! I need constrains for 2 value! In databse I have only one row where is date = 2017-01-01 and time = 1

Comment: You have defined an sql unique constraint on the time field (`test_module_time_uniq`). You just need to remove it, and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to prevent duplicated record use sql_constrains

```
class ModelClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.name'
    # your fields ...

    # add unique constraints 
    sql_constraints = [
            ('name_task_uniq', 'UNIQUE (name,date_deadline)',  'all ready got a task with this name and this date')
        ]

    # or use api.constrains if you constrains cannot be don in postgreSQL
    @api.constrains('name', 'date_deadline')
    def _check_existing(self):
        # add you logic to check you constrain
```

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_module_time_uniq"
>   DETAIL: Key (time)=(1) already exists.

This error is thrown by the postgres not odoo you all ready have a unique constrain for time only you need to drop it first

NB: Who added the constrains unique is it you when you where testing you code or is someone else? Answer this by comment ^^

```
ALTER TABLE project_task DROP CONSTRAINT test_module_time_uniq;
```

Comment: After uninstall and again install module all work fine!

Comment: yes because you added the constrain in odoo then you removed the code but odoo will not remove the the constrains after he create it this why. Keep in mind you define some think in odoo don't remove the code but unset if  for example in action if you do < field name ="domain">[something]</field>  don't removet it but unset the value < field name ="domain">[]</field> otherwise the domain will steal there but you don't way the result it not what you want...

Answer (score 2):

You can use something along those lines:

```py
@api.constrains('name', 'date_deadline')
def _check_existing(self):
    # Search for entry with these params, and if found:
        # raise ValidationError('Item already exists')
```